# Grails 3: Changing Ports on a Multi-Project Build with an Angular Profile

Tags: angular, grails, gradle

I'm trying to change the ports for a Grails 3.3.4 Multi-project build: one with an angular profile and one with a web profile.

I used this tutorial [Grails Multi-Project Build](http://guides.grails.org/grails-multi-project-build/guide/index.html) and this tutorial [Combining the Angular Profile Projects](http://guides.grails.org/angular2-combined/guide/index.html) to set up an app that looks kind of like this:

```
coffee-app-stack
    coffee (web)
    coffee-ui (angular)
```

"Coffee" is just one of many apps that we're upgrading from Grails 2.5.6, and we'll be moving over all of our traditional controller/gsp architecture to angular in phases.  These apps all comprise our "coffee platform" and may be running at the same time in dev, as in:

```
creamer-app-stack
    creamer (web)
    creamer-ui (angular)
    creamer-plugin (plugin)
```

So we'll need to make sure that non-conflicting ports and context paths are defined for each app stack.  I updated the application.yml's port and path for each project and made this update in the angular project:

```
in src/main/client/src/index.html, change <base href="/" /> to be <base href="/coffee-ui/" />
```

After a few tweaks to the images, the default apps rendered fine on the correct ports with the correct contextPaths with a parallel boot `gradlew bootRun --parallel --stacktrace --info`

EXCEPT, I get this in the browser console of the angular profile which is now running on http://localhost:4230/coffee-ui/#/index:

**GET http://localhost:8080/application net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

If I expand the twistie, the trace indicates that the issue is coming from core.es5.js and zone.js (with XHR_LISTENER's target field cropping up a fair amount).

The web profile is running fine with a FakeController (groovy/gsp) on: http://localhost:8110/coffee/fake/index

Can someone please tell me where the angular profile is looking for its associated application?

I suspect that this is probably to do with my conflating the angular profile from a client/server multi profile into one as outlined in the second tutorial and then changing the port.

However, this whole architecture is pretty divergent from Grails 2, I don't have much experience with gradle, and I don't know a useful place to begin fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

NVM!

It's in `coffee-ui/src/main/client/src/environments/environment.ts`  I believe.

I had to write it all out to find it!  Y'all are like the remote equivalent of fresh eyes...